# Python - unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, function, range

I've had a look at other questions on stackoverflow but they are different and don't seem to apply to this question, so here goes.

I've written a simple script that gives me a print out of every number between 1-49 and puts it into a list using the range function.

Now I have defined a function to work out what numbers are odd and what numbers are even, here is my code:

```
def check(number):
    if number%2==0:
        print "Even Numbers:",(number)
    else:
        print "Odd Numbers:",(number)


a = range(1,50)

print a

check(a)
```

I get the following error when I run the script:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

So I know that this means the % operator cannot doesn't support 'lists' or 'ints', but how can I fix it?

I tried this:

```
def check(number):
    if number%2==0:
        print "Even Numbers:",(number)
    else:
        print "Odd Numbers:",(number)


a = range(1,50)

b = str(a)

check(str(a))
```

But get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "showEvenNumbers.py", line 12, in <module>
    check(str(a))
  File "showEvenNumbers.py", line 2, in check
    if number%2==0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

So I'm a bit unsure what to do.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to iterate over the list in some way.

Comment: Thanks mat, I had a blank moment. I realized after I posted the question and Blender + you got me thinking about what I was trying to do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`a` is a list, but `check` expects a single integer. You need to iterate over the list:

```
for item in a:
    check(item)
```

Comment: That makes sense, I knew it'd be something simple. Thanks Blender. It works now. I was thinking that the (number) needed a single integer but I missed it. Will accept once it lets me.